# Application-shipped python does not autoset site-dirs correctly

Tags: python, distribution

The team I work in is developping an application (for now, on Windows) which is scriptable with python. A python 2.6 is installed alongside Application.exe, so as end users won't have to install python on their workstations.

I have not personnaly chosen the said distribution of python, and I find it quite strange, and don't even know where it came from (it was there when i started the job). It's a plain python.exe, alongside a python26.dll, python26.zip and some .pyd and .dll with them.
The content of python26.zip looks like what there would be in a lib/ directory.

The dir structure looks like this:

```
ApplicationDir/
    ├ Application.exe
    ├ Application.dll
    ├ _Application.pyd
    ├ python.exe
    ├ python.dll
    ├ python26.zip
    ├ _sqlite3.pyd
    ├ sqlite3.dll
    ├ select.pyd
    ├ _socket.pyd
    └ [... some more pyd follow]
```

Now I'd like to include some pure python packages of my own, which should work with my application (such as talking with a database, etc).

I was expecting that if I proceeded with a ./lib/site-packages/ that would work.

```
ApplicationDir/
    ├ Application.exe
    ├ ...
    └ lib/
        └ site-packages/
            ├ foo-1.2.egg
            ├ bar-0.9.egg
            └ more-libs.pth
```

The more-libs.pth content:

```
./foo-1.2.egg
./bar-0.9.egg
```

My assumption was wrong, and this is a big issue.
I've tested a "classic" python distribution by copying my system python installation (with dirs such as libs, Lib, DLLs) and it works.
But as I'm in charge of the python modules *only*, I'm not sure I can come and say "hey guys, let's distribute python another way".

I'm stuck here, as `site` does not seem to search the lib/site-packages dir.

Any thoughts? Maybe another python mini-distro that could search the right directories? Or should I patch site.py for it to meet my needs?

Cheers, and read you soon!

**EDIT**
I've found a workaround, with a patch to `site.py` inside the python26.zip archive.
I force-add a site-dir named "python-packages" that should be in the same directory as my python.exe. I do this during the addsitepackages() function, which is called right after python is started.

Here's the patch :

```
285c285,290
< 
---
>                                      
>     #HACK for distribution with a packages site-dir
>     exec_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
>     sitedirs.append(os.path.join(exec_dir, 'python-packages'))
>     # end of hack
>
```

Comment: If anyone could tell me what this py distribution is, I would also be much grateful :)

Comment: I should add that in this environment sys.prefix and sys.userprefix are empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ApplicationDir/lib/site-packages in your sys.path:

```
import sys, os
sys.path += [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib', 'site-packages')]
```

Or using environment variables:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/lib/site-packages
```

Or check sysconfig module:

```
import sysconfig
print sysconfig.get_config_vars()
```

For example, platlib is installed (for a posix_prefix) in `{platbase}/lib/python{py_short_version}/site-packages` (according to sysconfig.py)

Comment: Actually, i can add
 
 
    `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'lib', 'site-packages')`
 
 
For my .pth file to be interpreted correctly, I should add it to my site dirs:
 
    `site.addsitedir(some_path)`
 

What I would like, would be this path to be already added when I start python, so as no "manual operation" is needed.

Comment: So use PYTHONPATH environment variable :)

Comment: Sorry, forgotten about the PYTHONPATH part in my previous comment. I can't use it because it has the same effect as sys.path.append: it does not add the directory as a site-dir, so the .pth file is not parsed, and the ditributed eggs are not added to the path. It would work if I distributed the libs as plain directories, though. Also, I don't think I can set this ENV VAR because it could tamper with other python installations.

Comment: Ok, another test. Try to print in your app: import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_config_vars(). You might be able to found a correct path to put your packages in. As, instead of `lib/site-packages/`, try `lib/python2.6/site-packages/`

Comment: Alas, no sysconfig module, I'm bound to use a 2.6 python, and I see sysconfig is new in 3.2.

Comment: As for `lib/python2.6/site-packages/`, it does not work either. I put some `print` in `site.py` and it turns out that the list of auto-configured site dirs is empty at the end of `addsitepackages()`.

Comment: Weird, i got the sysconfig.py in my python 2.7 installation... ok :/

Comment: Ok, since site.py is automatically included before anything else.. do you think you can create a fake site.py at the root of your app, import the real one, and fix the `addsitepackages()` to make it work for you ?

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post. We've came to the same conclusions at the same time, I guess :)

Comment: That's not nice, you said that you didn't want to change the zip ! :D

Comment: Yes indeed ;) I may have to convince some people here that the patch is necessary, now. Or move to a "full" python distribution.